# Django data to Google Charts

Tags: javascript, django, charts, google-visualization

View:

```
def home(request,
    template = 'home.html'):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        data = [['jan'],[12],[-12]]

    context = {
        'data' : data,
    }
    return render(
        request, template, context)
```

Template:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart', 'bar']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);

function drawVisualization() {


  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'Month');
  data.addColumn('number');
  data.addColumn('number');

  data.addRows({{ data|safe }});

  // Create and draw the visualization.
  new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('visualization')).
      draw(data,
           {title: "blabla",
            width:600, height:400,
            bar: { groupWidth: '90%' },
            isStacked:"true",
            legend:"none" }
      );

}
</script>
```

I'm trying to get the array values to the chart rows but don't understand why this is not working. No graph is draw, everything else works though.

The overall aim is to store model fields in an array then use it to draw the chart, if I can't do this then I won't be able to proceed.

When I call {{ data }} in the template, it returns:

> **[[0], [12], [-12]]**

Is this the wrong format? How can I change this for Google Charts to accept it as row values?

Any help or direction would be appreciated,

thanks in advance

Comment: Could you please elaborate? I'm trying to produce a negative/positive column chart, so I need both positive and negative value. It works when I set the value of rows directly in the script, but if I do it in the view, and return the values of the rows (as I have done above), nothing is drawn.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

according to the data table definition in the code, there are three columns...

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('string', 'Month');
data.addColumn('number');
data.addColumn('number');
```

but from reading the question, sounds like you only need two...

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('string', 'Month');
data.addColumn('number');
```

and to add a single row of values, the format should be...

```
['Month', 0]
```

to add all the rows, using `addRows`, the format should be...

```
[
  ['Month',   0],
  ['Month',  12],
  ['Month', -12]
]
```

In your views context, change `'data' : data` to `'data': json.dumps(data)`

It is crucial to use json either in javascript, or in view.

Comment: Thanks a lot WhiteHat, I still wanted 3 columns, because the negative and positive can be in same month. I tried your format and it worked, thanks a lot, now I can finally connect it to database.